# Swimlane/ngx-ui change buttons' labels from Alert/Prompt

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m using ngx-ui from Swimlane: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-ui/

There is an alert/promp/confirm component that behaves as the browser's native.
The problem is that there is nothing in the docs that says if it is possible to change the label from the buttons.
There is only one example:

```
alertService.confirm({ title: 'Alert SOC', content: 'Intrusion Happened!!!' })
```

Does anyone know if it´s possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible with the alert service, but it looks easy to customize if you use a dialog.

```
<ng-template #dialogTmpl let-context="context">
<p>Custom dialog</i></p>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn">
    Custom button text
  </button>
</ng-template>
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  (click)="openDialog({ title: 'Alert!', template: dialogTmpl })">
  Open Dialog
</button>
```

And in the .ts:

```
import { DialogService } from '@swimlane/ngx-ui';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('dialogTmpl') dialogTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(public dialogMngr: DialogService) { }
  openDialog(options): void {
    this.dialogMngr.create(options);
  }
}
```